# How can I fix this error when i try to add a database DataSource to visual studio "Table mysql.proc doesn't exist"

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, database-connection, mysql-workbench

I have:

Visual Studio2017 Community 
Mysql Server 8.0 
MySql for Visual Studio 2.0.5 
MySql Connector Net 8.0.18 
MySql Workbench 8.

Can I solve it from workbench ? or do i have to install something or a different version of something?
I heard something related to "mysql_upgrade" but that doesn't work because it says its deprecated.
Any ideas how i cand make it work?
I want to have acces to that database on a windows form app for a project regarding sport attendance for students.
Ps: Im a begginer on MySql, also on Visual Studio.

Comment: MySql for Visual Studio is only at Version 1.29 stable, 205 is still in development. unistall it and use the ga version of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed MySql for Visual studio 1.2.9 and MySql Connector 6.9.8 and it works now (i also heard it is important to install mysql for vs first and then the connector, also did this). And it worked!